# Filtering WFS-features during Download using R

Tags: r, wfs, cql-filter

I need to download specific features of the following WFS:

"https://www.gds.hessen.de/wfs2/aaa-suite/cgi-bin/alkis/vereinf/wfs"

I would like to download 1500 specific features, filtered by "gemarkung" = x, "flur" = y, "flstnrzae" = z and "flstnrnen" = q.

But I don`t know, how to include the filter within the URL in R.

How should I write the code to make it work?

So far, I managed to download 1000 not-filtered features with the following code:

```
wfs_bwk <- "https://www.gds.hessen.de/wfs2/aaa-suite/cgi-bin/alkis/vereinf/wfs"
url <- parse_url(wfs_bwk)
url$query <- list(service = "wfs",
                  version = "2.0.0", # facultative
                  request = "GetFeature",
                  typenames = "ave:Flurstueck",
                  count=1000)
request <- build_url(url)
request

bel_regions <- read_sf(request)
```

But now I would like to download 1500 specific features, filtered by "gemarkung" = x, "flur" = y, "flstnrzae" = z and "flstnrnen" = q.

```
bwk_client <- WFSClient$new(wfs_bwk, 
                        serviceVersion = "2.0.0")
bwk_client$
  getCapabilities()$
  findFeatureTypeByName("ave:Flurstueck")$
  getDescription() %>%
  map_chr(function(x){x$getName()})
```

I tried it with adding a cql-filter to the url, but the filter is ignored.

```
url$query <- list(service = "wfs",
                  version = "2.0.0", # facultative
                  request = "GetFeature",
                  typenames = "ave:Flurstueck",
                  cql_filter="flur='2'",
                  count=1000)
request <- build_url(url)
request
```

used packages: ows4R, sf, httr

Comment: then where does the WFSClient function come from? Have you not listed the packages you are using? I can tell you've used `sf` but also I guess something for working with WFS data sources?

Comment: WFS service isn't provided by GeoServer software, software here is XtraServer

Answer (score 1):

You can add an SQL query to `read_sf` - construct it by pasting things together and you'll get a subset. I think this query is translated to WFS-speak and sent to the server for the server to comput (but possibly it still fetches all the records and does the selection locally, but I don't think so).

```
> bel_regions2 <- read_sf(request, query="select * from Flurstueck where flur = 2")
> dim(bel_regions2)
[1] 144  24
```

If you want 1500 records you'll have to change the count in the URL as well, I guess.

Comment: I guess, the code first tries to download everything and filters the data afterwards. When I leave out count in the URL, it does process longer and then gives me an error.. Unfortunately, the data is too large for a complete download.                                      
Fehler: Cannot open "https://www.gds.hessen.de/wfs2/aaa-suite/cgi-bin/alkis/vereinf/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=ave%3AFlurstueck"; The file doesn't seem to exist.
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
 GDAL Error 1: HTTP error code : 504

Comment: I suspect the server doesn't support server-side queries. The WFS driver doc says it tries to convert OGR SQL to OGC Filter but reverts to "get everything" if there's no OGC Filter support on the server. Looking at the GetCapabilities response it looks like it might... Hmmm...